# What is the purpose of the exchange method in the RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, httprequest, resttemplate

I am currently sending a resource to a client, I am using code that has been done already and I am modifying it, there is a line shown below in this code that I don't understand. Well I understand that I am sending or posting a resource, I understand this method takes the url of the client, that it takes the type of HTTP request for example in this case POST, but I dont understant why this method takes nService.getStringHttpEntityWithPayload(payLoad) and Resource.class? Also the response entity it is returning will it be a class only or a class with a status and a headers?

```
ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                eURL,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                nService.getStringHttpEntityWithPayload(payLoad),
                Resource.class);
```

Comment: What is `nService`?

Comment: @George it is a service that has the method public HttpEntity<String> getStringHttpEntityWithPayload(String payload) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        return new HttpEntity(payload, headers);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why this method takes nService.getStringHttpEntityWithPayload(payLoad) and Resource.class?

The method `getStringHttpEntityWithPayload` is returning a `HttpEntity` which is composed of a body and header data to be sent to a URL. The method is creating the request message by adding the content type header, letting the receiving service know that the body contains JSON data.

The parameter `Resource.class` is used to determine what class to deserialize the response  body from the service into. It defines the generic type of the return value: `ResponseEntity<Resource>`.

> Also the response entity it is returning will it be a class only or a class with a status and a headers?

I'm not sure what you mean by "class only". The `ResponseEntity` is similar to `HttpEntity` (in fact `class ResponseEntity<T> extends HttpEntity<T>`). The `ResponseEntity` class contains the response body and headers, as well as the HTTP Status code of the response.